# Biztalk throttling performance counter interpretation

Tags: biztalk

As per MSDN performance counter value 
Message delivery throttling state >1 indicates throttling
or
Message publishing throttling state >2 indicates throttling

what should be interpreted if 
Message delivery throttling state  >0 and <1
or
Message publishing throttling state >0 and < 2

Does this mean no throttling  or no significant throttling

Answer (score 2):

That value indicates the *reason* for throttling, not the degree of throttling.

So, you will never see a fractional value, only 0, no throttling, through 11, to indicate the reason for throttling.

Comment: This is not true  i did get through perfromance log anlyzer fractional values

Comment: Then it must be displaying an average over time or other calculation.  0-11 (whole numbers) are the only values used by that counter.  It will never, under any circumstances, return fractional values.

Answer (score 1):

Different values has different meaning for these counters. the value of 0 means no throttling. All other values mean there is throttling going on. Each non 0 value indicate why throttling is taking place. You can find details of these counters and their value meaning on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa578302.aspx)

Comment: Thanks vikas, but your answer does not addres my specific question about the two specific counters , it is clear from MSDN document  value of zero means throttling but next value mentioned is 1 ,2 respectively  so my question is w.r. value >0 but less than 1

Comment: If I understood yr question correctly, the counter  won't have value between 0 and 1. It will be either 0 or one of the listed value.